# Задание по MySQL

Tags: mysql

**У меня есть задание.**

## Здравствуйте!

Создайте базу данных, которая будет состоять из трёх табличек: items, users, orders. Лучше чтобы вы создали её вручную, но если не хотите этого делать, то вот SQL файл, который вы можете импортировать в БД через графический редактор PhpMyAdmin.

Из таблицы users выберите лишь пользователя, у которого поле login равен "john".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из таблицы items выберите лишь те товары, которые принадлежат к категории hats.

В таблицу orders поместите новые заказы. В качестве user_id указываейте id пользователя что вы выбрали из таблицы users, а в качестве item_id указывайте id товаров, что вы выбрали из таблицы items.

После добавления всех значений в таблицу orders выведите на экран содержимое таблицы orders в следующем формате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для проверки задания отправьте нам Python файл с реализацией этого задания. Базу данных отправлять не надо, так как она остается такой же.

1. Каким образом повставлять id кодом?
2. В таблицу orders поместите новые заказы. В качестве user_id указываейте id пользователя что вы выбрали из таблицы users, а в качестве item_id указывайте id товаров, что вы выбрали из таблицы items.  После добавления всех значений в таблицу orders выведите на экран содержимое таблицы orders в следующем формате: Вот это не понятно

**Подскажите пожалуйста. *Вообще* не понимаю**

Comment: Если вообще не понимаете - почитайте материалы для начала по Python и MySQL. Что толку, если кто-то за вас всё напишет, а вы так и будете дальше ничего не понимать.

Comment: Мне не нужно полностью решение, мне нужна подсказка. И кстати мне 10 лет и это нормально что я что-то не понимаю. Я пытался раные способы и читал информацию.

Comment: Напишите тогда список конкретных вопросов - что именно вам непонятно. "Всё непонятно" - это значит человек не пытался разобраться сам.

Comment: Я точно не знаю как сформулировать правильно вопрос. Каким образом повставлять id кодом.

Comment: Как сделать чтобы определить эти id и вывести так. Вручную или специпльный код какой-то? Все эти создание таблиц, столбцов и т. д. это оставлялся sql файл который можно было импортировать в phpMyAdmin и оно создасться.

Comment: `В таблицу orders поместите новые заказы. В качестве user_id указываейте id пользователя что вы выбрали из таблицы users, а в качестве item_id указывайте id товаров, что вы выбрали из таблицы items.

После добавления всех значений в таблицу orders выведите на экран содержимое таблицы orders в следующем формате:` Вот это не понятно

Comment: Вы это в самом вопросе всё напишите, отдельными пунктами. Чтобы было понятно, на что отвечать. Вопрос можно редактировать.

Answer (score 2):

В 10 начать изучать программирование - это круто! Не бросай, иди вперед и не слушай умников.

1. Почитай про работу с базой данных MySQL - запросы типа SELECT и INSERT
2. Почитай про то, как с помощью Python делать SQL-запросы и отображать полученный результат в нужном виде.

---

1.1 Из таблицы users выберите лишь пользователя, у которого поле login равен "john":

```
SELECT FROM database.users WHERE login = 'john';
```

1.2 Из таблицы items выберите лишь те товары, которые принадлежат к категории hats:

```
SELECT FROM database.items WHERE category = 'hats';
```

2. В таблицу orders поместите новые заказы. В качестве user_id указываейте id пользователя что вы выбрали из таблицы users, а в качестве item_id указывайте id товаров, что вы выбрали из таблицы items

Не видя саму базу, сложно написать оптимальный запрос. Какая структура у таблицы "заказы"? Сколько строк получится после выполнения запроса из пункта 1.2?

Если не очень много, то вставить в таблицу заказов можно такими запросами:

```
INSERT into database.orders (user_id, item_id) VALUES(45,11);
INSERT into database.orders (user_id, item_id) VALUES(45,12);
INSERT into database.orders (user_id, item_id) VALUES(45,18);
INSERT into database.orders (user_id, item_id) VALUES(45,19);
INSERT into database.orders (user_id, item_id) VALUES(45,22);
```

45 - например id Джона.
11, 12, 18, 19, 22 - требуемые Джону товары (шапки).

3. Для получения результата как на картинке тебе, кроме SELECT-запроса нужно 2 раза использовать запрос LEFT JOIN. Он не сложный. Попробуй сам разобраться.
   Суть его в том, что ты, по сути, делаешь три запроса и объединяешь полученные данные, лишнее потом отбрасываешь. Объединение делаешь по id пользователя и товаров.

Как выполнять MySQL-запросы с помощью Python - попробуй сам погуглить ;)

---

P.S. По поводу уроков Дударя: лично я их не смотрел, но в сети его не особо хвалят. Возможно, лучше найти другой источник для обучения.

Comment: **Спасибо большое!** Теперь более менее понятно, буду разбираться.

Насчёт Дударя к сожалению уже купил курс, придётся до конца идти.